# Failed to install Twisted under "Big Sur"

Tags: twisted

I failed to install twisted under "Mac OS Big Sur" with the following error:
“build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/src/twisted/test/raiser.o
clang: error: invalid version number in 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11'
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1”

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same kind of problem with installing pyaudio for Python with

```
pip install pyaudio
```

I get

```
clang: error: invalid version number in 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11'
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: How is this an answer? I won't downvote low-rep users, but move this to a comment.